# jQuery UI menubar, position submenu absolute left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have created a jQuery UI navigation menu, using the menubar widget.  It works how I expected except I would like it to behave slightly differently.  As you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/hcharge/DebVr/ the submenu expands out and is positioned relative to the link that was clicked.

I would like it to expand out and stick to the left of the navigation bar, no matter which link was clicked, the submenu will always stay the same width.  Like this image...

[image]

I've tried setting a position relative to the container and absolutely positioning the submenu, however I think that jQuery UI positioning is overriding this.  Any advice would be great, cheers.

Edit: this needs to be done with JS as it has to be clicks and not hover actions that trigger the dropdowns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do it all only with CSS?

See http://jsfiddle.net/DebVr/8/

Note: the background is blue in order to see the white borders.

**Edit:**

If you want some functionality, you can add it later, but I think that the basis should be with CSS.

See my code with some functionality here: http://jsfiddle.net/DebVr/11/

```
var links=$('#bar1>li>a').each(function(index,obj) {
  obj.tabindex=index+1;
});
$('#bar1>li>a').focus(
    function(){$(this).siblings('ul').show();}
);
$('#bar1>li>a').blur(
    function(){$('#bar1>li>ul').hide();}
);
```

**Edit 2:**

If you want to hide again the submenu when clicked, use the following code:

```
var links=$('#bar1>li>a').each(function(index,obj) {
  obj.tabIndex=index+1;
});
$('#bar1>li>a').focus(function(){
    $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('show');
});
$('#bar1>li>a').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).siblings('ul').toggleClass('show');
});

$('#bar1>li>a').blur(function(){
   $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('show');
});
```

And CSS:

```
#bar1>li>ul.show{
    display:block;
}
```

See it here: [http://jsfiddle.net/DebVr/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/DebVr/14/)

**Edit 3**:

In the code above, I replaced `obj.tabindex` with `obj.tabIndex`, and updated the jsfiddle.

The problem is that if you click on the submenu, the anchor loses focus and then the submenu dissapears. On Chrome it can be easily fixed setting the `focus` event to `#bar1>li` instead of `#bar1>li>a`, but then the event doesn't work on firefox... I'm working on a solution, but meanwhile you can use [http://jsfiddle.net/DebVr/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/DebVr/14/).

**Edit 4:**

Finally, the fixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/DebVr/18/

It works on Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: I'm afraid it has to be click only, not with hover, and the links need to be able to be tabbed between each other, thanks very much for that implementation though...

Comment: @hcharge See my edited answer, I have added some functionalities.

Comment: thanks very much for that, it looks really good and on the right track, i just don't know how to get it to click to show the child ul and then click off to hide again, do you know how you could implement this? thanks again for your help

Comment: thanks so much for your latest revision, it still doesn't really work as if you click on another link then the one you're on doesn't close, it also needs to close if you click outside of the dropdown like my original fiddle

Comment: this is incredible, thanks very much for your hard work, much better than the jquery ui method...